# Tracking; How to deal with tracked features that disappear and become visible again later?

Tags: objects, tracking

I'm tracking a box in a video by tracking dots on each side, and at certain points in the animation a side of the box disappears, and then later on that side is visible again.  As a result, the dots that are on that side (which I am tracking) disappear, and then reappear.  What do I do with that time in the middle, where those dots are invisible?  Do I just stop tracking?  How?

How do I get Blender to know that the time in the middle is irrelevant?  Can I get those trackers to stop tracking and restart when those tracker dots are visible again?  I'm afraid that Blender takes that time in the middle into account, thus causing the tracking of the object to totally fail.

I hope this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is a button that cuts it fro a certain set of frames, and then you can add it back when it reappears

Comment: A little bit more detail, e.g. a screenshot, would make this a better answer.

Comment: Yeah, could you add a screenshot of the button?  also, how would I "add it back"?  Were you saying I should animate the button?

Answer (score 0):

Track until the point where the object is no longer visible (or trackable).

Then go to the frame where it re-appears, create a new tracker and track again.

[image]

Then select both trackers (shift select both) and do Join trackers.
It is very important that you join the trackers, so that blender knows it is dealing with the same object and not a new one.